# How to list branches that contain another branch in git

Tags: git, branch

Can someone explain/provide an example of how to list branches that contains another branch in git?

can I use the contain attribute?

Comment: Are you looking for branches that contain a specific branch, or "any branch that contains any other branch"?

Comment: branches that contain a specific branch, thx

Answer (score 8):

A branch name is just a fancy pointer to a given commit (in other words, it's a [commitish](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitglossary#gitglossary-aiddefcommit-ishacommit-ishalsocommittish)), so you can look for branches that contain it with the `--contains` option:

```
$ git branch --contains my_branch
```

And if you want to check remote branches as well, you can add the `-r` flag:

```
$ git branch -r --contains my_branch
```

Comment: *refspec* is the wrong technical word, as it means `[+]<name>[:[<name>]]` in Git. Maybe you wanted *reference* here?

Comment: @torek yup, you're right. Lapsed concentration there for a moment. I meant to say commitish.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to know about `git branch --contains whatever-branch`. Use -r if you want to check remote branches as well.